# password option is not working in Zip file

Tags: c#, passwords, zip, compression, dotnetzip

Am creating a Password enabled zip file using [DotNetZip Library](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/downloads/get/258012) following is the code for this:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(cryptPath, "*.*");
    foreach (string f in Files)
    {
        zip.AddFile(f);                       
    }                   
    zip.Password = "mypassord";
    zip.Save(cryptPath + @"\output.zip");
}
```

Everything works fine except the password option is not working, no password is prompted while opening the file? how can i enable this?

Comment: I think that you need to specify the encryption as well: 

zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be using the password for encryption when you add the files so setting the password **before** adding the files worked for me:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "mypassword";

    string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(cryptPath, "*.*");
    foreach (string f in Files)
    {
        zip.AddFile(f);                       
    }                   

    zip.Save(cryptPath + @"\output.zip");
}
```